# Failed to start countdown for the second time during operation

Tags: javascript, countdown

I am using the following code and giving a second click to the same start countdown button not clean the first process, so there are two counts at the same time. How do I stop the first process when the second start?
Thank you very much in advance.

```
function countdown(element, minutes, seconds) {
// Fetch the display element
var el = document.getElementById(element);

// Set the timer
var interval = setInterval(function() {
    if(seconds == 0) {
        if(minutes == 0) {
            (el.innerHTML = "STOP!");     

            clearInterval(interval);
            return;
        } else {
            minutes--;
            seconds = 60;
        }
    }

    if(minutes > 0) {
        var minute_text = minutes + (minutes > 1 ? ' minutes' : ' minute');
    } else {
        var minute_text = '';
    }

    var second_text = seconds > 1 ? '' : '';
    el.innerHTML = minute_text + ' ' + seconds + ' ' + second_text + '';
    seconds--;
}, 1000);
}
//Start as many timers as you want

var start1 = document.getElementById('timer1');
var start2 = document.getElementById('timer2');

start1.onclick = function() {
countdown('countdown1', 0, 15);
}

start2.onclick = function() {
countdown('countdown2', 0, 10);
}
//extra button and counter    
<div id='countdown1'></div>
<div id='countdown2'></div>
<input id="timer1" type="button" value="Start timer 1" />
<input id="timer2" type="button" value="Start timer 2" />
```

Comment: You could add a global `var` that returns `true` or `false` wether there is a timer working or not (you declare it with `false`, set it to `true` when you start a timer and set it back to `false` when the countdown is over) .. Then at the beginning of your function, if the `var` is `true`, you `return` immediatly

Comment: Can you help me with the code to do it?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could save the interval variable as an attribute of the countdown element. Then, at the beginning of the countdown function, check if the interval attribute has been defined for that element. If so, call clearInterval on it before starting a new interval.

Answer (score 0):

```
clearInterval(intervalvalue)
```

will be helpful to .

[Working code here](http://jsfiddle.net/Xxxd3/1787/)